# How to set the page height when using window.print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I want to print a page via pos printer, but now it prints too long blank page.
Here is my js code.

```
<script>
  $("#print").click( function (){
      var div_height = document.getElementById("yu_jie_dan").clientHeight;
      var printContents = document.getElementById("yu_jie_dan").innerHTML;
      w = window.open("", 'name', 'resizable=1',false);
      w.document.write("<body style='width: 230px;font-size: 30px;'>");
      w.document.write(printContents);
      w.document.write("</body>");
      w.print();
      w.close();
  })
</script>
```

I want to set my page `width` to `230px` and the `height` is `auto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not make the page longer,at last I add a div for this page.Remember,the div must contain some words that can make this page longer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pseudo class in css that will take effect only when you are trying to print a html page.

```css
#page-id__or__div-id: print {
  // Add style here that you want to see in printed documents
}
```

Comment: I try this.But it not work ,now it print too short.I change the js code.I update  in the question.